# Integrable functions and inequalties

Tags: calculus

Let $f,g:[a,b]\to \mathbb R$ be integrable functions. Assuming that $f^2$ and $g^2$  and $fg$ are also integrable, prove that

$2\int_a^b fg \le \int_a^b f^2 + \int_a^b g^2\,.$

Do i need to somehow prove f*g is less than f^2 and g^2 ?

Comment: Yes, your idea is correct: we do have $2fg\leq f^2+g^2$.

Comment: So how do i use that in a integral proof

Comment: Make use of the positivity of the integral: a non-negative function will have a non-negative integral. You can apply this to $f^2 + g^2 - 2fg$.

Comment: So something like